# R: Using Apply Function to clean likert answers

Tags: r, apply

I have a survey where users have filled in answers to questions on a likert scale. The software we are using has put text into the answers when all i want is numbers so an example is `NEITHER AGREE NOR DISAGREE4`. I want to convert it to `4`

I have R code that does this where it looks for a number in the cell of the dataframe for column 18 and extracts the number from it if it exists

```
as.numeric(ifelse(grepl("[0-9]",df[,18]),as.numeric(gsub(x = df[,18],"[A-z]","")), df[,18]))
```

I would like to be able to do this for cols `18:134`

I can do this with a for loop, i guess but i think this is a perfect example of how to use one of the apply functions and i would like to learn.

Thanks

Comment: If found, is the number always at the end?

Comment: Hi @Julius, The number would replace the original value so `NEITHER AGREE NOR DISAGREE4` to `4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
apply(df[,18:134], 2, function(x) gsub("[^0-9]", "", x))
```