# Converting Factors to Numbers: Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r

This question is somewhat related to a question i asked [R: Using Apply Function to clean likert answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819788/r-using-apply-function-to-clean-likert-answers/35820186#35820186)

I have a likert scale but everything is text. I wish to convert the columns to factors and then to numbers. There are missing values in the answers

```
df[,104:123] <- as.numeric(apply(df[,104:105], 2, 
                                  function (x) factor(x,levels =  c("NEVER","RARELY","SOMETIMES","MOST OF THE TIME","ALWAYS"))))
```

I however get the following error: `Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion`

IN fact it has converted everything to `NA`
I ran the code without the `as.numeric` conversion and it seems ok

Below is the output for two columns
`apply(df[,104:123], 2, function(x) unique(x))`

```
$Ans.1
[1] ""                 "SOMETIMES"        "MOST OF THE TIME"   "RARELY"           "ALWAYS"           "NEVER"           

$Ans.2.
[1] ""                 "SOMETIMES"        "MOST OF THE TIME" "RARELY"           "ALWAYS"           "NEVER"
```

Can anyone see the problem in my code

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use `lapply` instead of `apply` as the apply returns a `matrix` and `matrix` can have only a single class. So, instead of `factor` it will be all `character` class if there is any element that is a `character`.  By using `as.numeric` on `character` class, we get all NAs.

```
df[,104:123] <- lapply(df[,104:123], function (x) 
 as.numeric(factor(x, levels =  c("NEVER","RARELY","SOMETIMES",
             "MOST OF THE TIME","ALWAYS"))))
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, thank you very much for answering so quickly. Just to clarify for myself. the `factor` aspect should only return factors which then are converted to either numbers or `NA` which the apply should work with no? In relation to your answer, do i have to unlist the returning list in order to update the df? Thanks Again

Comment: @JohnSmith By assigning to `df[,104:123] <- ` we are replacing the numeric values in the original dataset

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some reproducible data?

Else, see my example of `to_value` from [sjmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjmisc), which might work for you:

```
x <- factor(c("ALWAYS", "SOMETIMES", "NEVER","RARELY","SOMETIMES","SOMETIMES", "MOST OF THE TIME","ALWAYS", "SOMETIMES"),
            levels =  c("NEVER","RARELY","SOMETIMES","MOST OF THE TIME","ALWAYS"))

table(x)

>  NEVER     RARELY     SOMETIMES MOST OF THE TIME     ALWAYS 
>      1          1             4                1          2 

table(sjmisc::to_value(x))

> 1 2 3 4 5 
> 1 1 4 1 2
```

You can also provide a data frame as argument:

```
df[,104:105] <- to_value(df[,104:105])
```